# laravel old version is not supporting php 8.0.8

Tags: laravel, version

I have installed php 8.0.8 on my local computer. Laravel new projects work perfect. But when I try to run Old projects it shows me error.  When I try to run command

```
composer install
```

It gives me the error below:

```
      Problem 1
    - jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper is locked to version 5.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper 5.0.1 requires ext-soap * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's soap extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

When I run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It shows this error:

```
    Generating optimized autoload files Class App\Http\Controllers\Vendor\OrderController 
 located in C:/Users/Muhammad Adnan/Downloads/test-upwork-master/spree-retail/app\Http\Controllers\temp\OrderController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Resources\profile\AddressesResponse located in C:/Users/Muhammad Adnan/Downloads/test-upwork-master/spree-retail/app\Http\Resources\Profile\AddressesResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-autoload-dump script
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\test-upwork-master\spree-retail\bootstrap\app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\test-upwork-master\spree-retail\artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\test-upwork-master\spree-retail\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\test-upwork-master\spree-retail\bootstrap\app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\test-upwork-master\spree-retail\artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\test-upwork-master\spree-retail\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

Comment: Well you should not install an old version on PHP 8. Some functionality will not work. That is the reason you can't install the version

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, older versions of Laravel doesn't not support newer versions of PHP. Laravel 6 is the minimal version for PHP 8.0 support (and it is already pretty old from a web development perspective).

Of course, this is for a fresh installation, you might have code in your project that is also not PHP 8.0 compatible.

About this error:

```php
  Problem 1
- jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper is locked to version 5.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
- jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper 5.0.1 requires ext-soap * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's soap extension.
```

The problem will be easy to fix, just install the soap extension. You seem on Windows so it should already installed but disabled.

You will have to uncomment `;extension=soap.dll` in your `php.ini` file (or maybe in the `ext` directory located in your php directory, it depends).

There will probably be other extensions required but disabled, to get a full list execute `composer check`.

This is what is preventing composer from installing your dependencies (which lead `Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in` to when you are calling `composer dump-autoload`).

Answer (score -1):

I searched out and found a solution regarding this issue. Only single command is the solution
Note: Don't update composer.

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: NEVER install ignoring platform reqs. There is a reason that you can't install an old version on PHP 8